# Confidence Interval Calculated from Data Collected in Two Stages

Tags: confidence-interval, sampling

Assume that I collect a simple random sample of 400 widgets and calculate an estimate of the proportion of widgets in the population that are red along with the 95% confidence interval of the proportion. After looking at the result, I decide that I would like a tighter confidence interval and collect 400 additional widgets at random, adding them to the initial sample of 400 widgets. I once again calculate the proportion of widgets in the population that are red and the 95% confidence interval. Is this second 95% confidence interval actually a 95% confidence interval or does it need to be adjusted in some way in order to obtain 95% confidence because I collected the data in two stages? How should I adjust it if it indeed does need to be adjusted?